# Why can't I push multiple digit number in stack to calculate prefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, push

I'm writing a program where I'm converting a function to prefix and calculate.

```
from pythonds.basic import Stack

def doMath(op, op1, op2):

    if op == "*":
        return int(op1) * int(op2)

    elif op == "/":
        return int(op1) / int(op2)

    elif op == "+":
        return int(op1) + int(op2)

    elif op == "-":
        return int(op1) + int(op2)

def postfixEval(postfixExpr):

    operandStack = Stack()
    tokenList = postfixExpr.split()

    for token in tokenList:
        print(tokenList)
        print("this is token: ", token)

        if token in "0123456789":
            operandStack.push(token)
            print("pop: ",operandStack.peek())

        elif not operandStack.isEmpty():
            operand2 = operandStack.pop()
            operand1 = operandStack.pop()
            result = doMath(token, operand1, operand2)
            print (result)
            operandStack.push(result)

    return operandStack.pop()

print(postfixEval('7 8 + 3 2 + /'))
print(postfixEval("17 10 + 3 * 9 /"))
```

So when I run the first postfixEval it return 3.0, 
but at the second print it returns `IndexError: pop from empty list`
Apparently it's bc of the 2 digit numbers, how could I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: '17' is not in '0123456789'.

Comment: Next time, please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try:

```
if token in "0123456789":
    operandStack.push(token)
```

for `token = 17`, this shall fail since `17` is not in `0123456789`.
So change it to this:

```
try:
    if float(token):
        operandStack.push(token)
except:
    #your code here
```

---

**HOW THIS WORKS:**
When a type of `str` containing digits and numbers are passed, `float()` tries to convert it into float. This is only possible only if it is a number.

Comment: Your code will crash on the first non-numeric token.

Comment: This code doesnt crash for non numeric. He can add it to the operations

Comment: Sure it does crash. Try `float("*")`.

Comment: Please dont  downvote to make your answer prominent

Comment: @InfinityTM He edited the answer after my comments. Now, it it fine.

Comment: FP  number is mentioned in the post

Comment: This was it.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if token in "0123456789"` (checks if `token` is a substring of `"0123456789"`) with `if token.isdigit()` (checks if `token` consists of decimal digits).

Comment: This doesnt work with floats. Try this: `a='13.0' , a.is_digit()`

Comment: It is not clear if the code is meant to work with FP numbers. All examples are integer.

Comment: It is clear from `print(postfixEval('7 8 + 3 2 + /'))`

Comment: @Mr.Dark There is not a single FP number in the example.